# Add Konsole to favorites in Gnome3

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3

[How do I add eclipse to my gnome shell favorites?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58824/how-do-i-add-eclipse-to-my-gnome-shell-favorites)

[How can I add an application to the Favorites section of the Applications menu in CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170823/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-favorites-section-of-the-applications-menu-i)

Konsole doesn't seem to be recognizes as an "Activity." I am not sure if I need to make a .desktop file because it is already in the application menu under "System Tools". I made a file called konsole.desktop and it doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I add it to favorites?

Comment: Start it, then right click on its icon on the dash (the left bar) and select "Add to Favorites"

Comment: Unlike with other apps, when I launch Konsole and right click on it in the dock, there is "Add to Favorites" option in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press the Super key.
2. Type "Konsole" to search for it.
3. Drag the resulting icon to the dock.

You will now have the Konsole in the dock, but in my experience the konsole icon doesn't work like the others. The Konsole icon only launches Konsole. The launched Konsole becomes a second icon in the doc, which will also lack the menu option to add *that* the Favorites.

Ideally the Konsole icon could work like other icons and be used for both launching the application and also switching back to a running application.